# What lifestyle choices have the biggest impact on a local economy?

Tags: food, city-living, economy

As someone who lives in a city and expects that a sustainable world will be interdependent rather than isolated homesteads, I'm interested in where money (spent locally as an assumption) is best placed to help support a local economy. Who needs it most? What industries will keep it in local circulation?

Comment: I think you're going to have to narrow this down **a lot** for it to be answerable: people write whole books about this question as it is currently phrased.

Comment: Thanks. As someone who's new to the SE model, is it more appropriate to edit the original question or submit a modified version as a new question?

Comment: Try editing this one. If it gets buried by downvotes and close votes, then submit as a new question. If you want, come over to chat to try to knock the question into shape. It might take a little time, but we'll get there.

Comment: "people write whole books about this question" - it's the life's work of many people!

Comment: It's an interesting question, but broad questions like this can only be discussed, not *answered,* per se. As such, these type of talking-points and discussion questions are better asked in a discussion forum or chat room. It's just not well-suited to *this* type of Q&A site.

Comment: Hokay. I feel like there are metrics that would allow a solid quantitative answer, but I take your point. Another etiquette question: is it appropriate to delete the question or leave it here closed?

Comment: @AlexanderTD I saw your last comment only now. If you add the text '@<username>' to a post that person gets a notification about your comment (just like I did at the start of this comment). As to your question on deleting or leaving it closed; it doesn't matter. There are no answers to this question so you can delete it yourself if you want, or just leave it for now in case you do decide to edit and reopen it.